# Rails able to resolve namespaced model in development, but not on staging environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I ran into the following error on staging, but works fine locally.

`NameError (uninitialized constant Manager::Seller::Product)`

Line causing error in `/app/services/manager/admins/sellers/products/curation.rb`

```
module Manager
  module Admins
    module Sellers
      module Products
         class Curation
            ...
            def my_function
               @product.update(entity_id: @entity_id,
                               curation_status: Seller::Product.curation_statuses[:accepted])
             end
      ....
```

It works when making it absolute by appending `::` to `Seller::Product` in the code above, so that it will resolve it from top of the directory.

Weird thing: on my local/dev env, I do not get the error.

Am I doing the name-spacing/constant thing correctly or

- Is it cause of Rails 5 having `auto_reloading` in dev but not in staging/production or
- Am I missing setting in config/environments/staging.rb

*models/seller/product.rb*

```
  class Seller::Product < ApplicationRecord
      ...
  end
end
```

*models/seller.rb*

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
end
```

Refs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths

Comment: Does it work if you put this in your `application.rb`? `config.enable_dependency_loading = true`

Comment: Hey @Severin. Thanks for your suggestion. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: If you're running Rails 5.2, be aware that in production, autoloading is disabled by default. This could be the culprit.